# Vue to validate form field using method

Tags: vue.js

First of all, I'm new to Vue, so please bear with me.
I'm working on a codebase that was writing by someone else. The App is quite simple and is just a form to collect data. One of the fields is a postcode field and has the following validation:

```
postcodeRules: [v => !!v || "Please enter your postcode"]
```

Which if I understood correctly all it does is validates against an empty field. I'd like to add a method to be called to validate this field, such as:

```
postcodeRules: [v => !!v || "Please enter your postcode", v => this.checkPostcode(v) || "Postcode not valid"]
```

Where `checkPostcode()` would call an external API, however I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkPostcode' of undefined`.

I've also tried

```
postcodeRules: [v => !!v || "Please enter your postcode", v => checkPostcode(v) || "Postcode not valid"]
```

This is my whole code: https://gist.github.com/WagnerMatos/f884e97fe47c4553e6e5aaf3ebbec792

Any idea of how to get this working?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
This is the template code: https://gist.github.com/WagnerMatos/c2e45bdf00db06f98a109e6313dd35a8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `checkPostcode()` to the component `methods` in order to make it accessible from the component context and not have it under the `data` key. See the `Vue` documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods)

```html
<script>
    export default {
         methods: {
             checkPostcode(postcopde) {
                 console.log(postcopde);
             }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with context of *this* in arrow function. You can try this workaround, it's not beauty but works. You can use inner function to run logic inside it.

```js
data: () => ({
    postcode: 0,
    postcodeRules: [val => {
        if(!val) 
          return "Please enter your postcode"

        if(!checkPostcode(val)) {
          return "Postcode not serviced."
        }
        else {
          return true
        }

        function checkPostcode(postcode) {
          console.log(postcode)
          return false
        }
    }]
})
```

Comment: and @Kenneth I've tried that but I still get the same error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkPostcode' of undefined`

Comment: @Sosuke, I've added here:  https://gist.github.com/WagnerMatos/f884e97fe47c4553e6e5aaf3ebbec792

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK Yeah, but with html part of this component.

Comment: Just added. Thanks!

Comment: just added the html part of it @Sousuke

Comment: Your problem is with _this_ context, it is different in arrow function. I don't have idea how to solve this, but the simplest workaround will be to move validation logic inside rule.

Comment: Would you be able to add a example on how to fix/have the workaround? @Sousuke

Comment: I've tried your solution @Sousuke but then I got the following error: `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "rules". Expected Array, got Function`

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK I missed array before function, it should work now.